# AttributeError: module 'collection.views' has no attribute 'create_word'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, attributeerror, django-registration

I am attempting to create route for a form that will allow users to create their own words for a dictionary.

I keep receiving the following error `AttributeError: module 'collection.views' has no attribute 'create_word'` every time I attempt to run local server

Error calls attention to this line of code within the urls.py

```
path('accounts/create_word/', views.create_word, name='registration_create_word'),
```

Not sure what is the issue since I have defined the create_word method located within the views.py

```
def create_word(request):
        form_class = WordForm
        # if users are coming from a submitted form, do this
        if request.method == 'POST':
            #grab the data from the submitted form and apply it to the form
            form = form_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #create an instance but don't save
                word = form.save(commit=False)
                #set additional details
                word.user = request.user
                user.slug = slugify(word.name)
                #save the object
                word.save()
                # redirect to newly created word object
                return redirect('word_detail', slug=word.slug)
            #otherwise create the form
            else:
                form = form_class()

            return render(request, 'words/create_word.html', {
                'form': form,
            })
```

I also believe that I correctly imported the collection views

```
from collection.backends import MyRegistrationView
from collection import views
```

Would greatly appreciate some clarification on what I am missing or doing wrong

Comment: you can try to check the indentations inside `views.py` carefully.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks so much